# How to resolve inferred type containing Serializable

Tags: scala, scala-wartremover

Stumped on this one. Working with PlayJSON and their JsObject.

Wart remover is marking the `map` call with a carrot(^) and saying at that line Inferred type containing Serializable. Code is functional and working but wondering more about why tool is flagging this and how to remove this error.

```
    def getPrintVersionOfJsonObj(jsObj: JsObject): JsObject = {
     val fieldValueMap: Seq[(String,JsValue)] = jsObj.fields.map {
      case (fieldName, fieldValue: JsNumber)  => (fieldName, fieldValue)
      case (fieldName, fieldValue: JsBoolean) => (fieldName, fieldValue)
      case (fieldName, fieldValue: JsString)  => (fieldName, fieldValue)
      case (fieldName, fieldValue: JsArray)   => (fieldName, convertJsArrayToPrettyString(fieldValue))
      case (fieldName, fieldValue: JsObject)  => (fieldName, getPrintVersionOfJsonObj(fieldValue))
      case (fieldName, fieldValue: JsValue)   => (fieldName, JsString(Json.prettyPrint(fieldValue)))
  }

  JsObject(fieldValueMap)
}
```

JSObject.fields is `scala.collection.Seq[scala.Tuple2[scala.Predef.String, play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]`

What I find confusing is you have known return type for that val `fieldValueMap` and you know the type of `jsObj.fields`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it even compiles (I don't see how if it does)?

The first (for example) `case` of your `match`, returns 
`(String, JsNumber)`, while the fourth one returns (what seems to be) `(String, String)`. The only common super type of these two types is `Serializable`, so, that's what it ends up being.

Comment: the fourth one returns ```(String,JsString)``` and JsString is ```case class JsString(value: String) extends JsValue```

Comment: In that case, wartremover is wrong (provided that next line also returns a `JsValue`). Does the code actually compile?

Comment: yea compiles and works as intended recently we added wart remover to the project and was trying to work through the issues